# Excel VBA date format isse(need to apply filter or take pivot as end result)

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys problem is solved.

I found the error, i was picking dates in value format from.
and of the sheet was having format MM/DD/YYYY format, hence it was messing up whole o/p
thanks for the help.

---

Hi friends im facing a issue with a date type.

I have written a macro to pick up date value from various sheets in a workbook and paste one below the other.This works perfectly fine.(I am also picking various other columns along with date value as well)

Now after getting all the data stacked in one sheet one below the other.
I want to format the date in DD-MM-YY format.
for which i have written macro below.

```
 Sheets("Overall").Select
    Range("N2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
      Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yy"

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("N1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Now issue is when I am trying to take pivot or apply filter on this data.
Filter shows date in MM-DD-YY format.
which is wrong.
I am not able to take a pivot of this data due to this(As i have to prepare a pivot showing day wise sales).

I have changed my System default date format to DD-MM-YY also.

But still no luck.
Can anyone help me here.
I would attach the o/p if required.

looking for solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for the reply. I used your solution but still no luck. I am still getting date shown in MM-DD-YYYY format. Also when pivot is taken its not automatically arranging the date from 1st day till last day.